# Queue: Dequeue function crashes program

Tags: c++, list, queue

I am attempting to make a queue in c++ using a double linked list. I Have not fully tested everything since i am stuck at the step where you dequeue. I attempted to create a temp node, and move around stuff so when I call delete on the head node in the queue (called queue), and then set the head to a temp node which is the next element, (you can see in the code) but when I call delete, is where it crashes, according to MS Visual studios 2013. Also to add how weird this is, following the stack called, after delete is called, setPrev is called and set the prev node and crashes there. Now I never call this function during any of my destructors  deletes so any help will do. I will try my best to understand any answers but I am still new to c++ terminology. Below is my code. Oh one last thing, in main, all I did was call enqueue once, then dequeue once, then delete

```
Node Class
```

...

```
#ifndef TSDNODE_H
#define TSDNODE_H

template <class T>
class DNode
{
    private:
        DNode<T>* next;
        DNode<T>* prev;
        T data;

    public:
        DNode(T);
        void setNext(DNode<T>* next);
        void setPrev(DNode<T>* prev);
        DNode<T>* getNext() const;
        DNode<T>* getPrev() const;
        T getData() const;
        void setData(T data);
        ~DNode();
};

template <class T>
DNode<T>::DNode(T data)
{
    this->next = nullptr;
    this->data = data;
    this->prev = nullptr;
}

template <class T>
void DNode<T>::setNext(DNode<T>* next)
{
    this->next = next;
}

template <class T>
void DNode<T>::setPrev(DNode<T>* prev)
{
    this->prev = prev;
}

template <class T>
DNode<T>* DNode<T>::getNext() const
{
    return this->next;
}

template <class T>
DNode<T>* DNode<T>::getPrev() const
{
    return this->prev;
}

template <class T>
T DNode<T>::getData() const
{
    return this->data;
}

template <class T>
void DNode<T>::setData(T data)
{
    this->data = data;
}

template <class T>
DNode<T>::~DNode()
{
    delete this->next;
    delete this->prev;
    this->next = nullptr;
    this->prev = nullptr;
}

#endif  /* TSDNODE_H */
```

....

```
Queue Class
```

....

```
#ifndef TSQUEUE_H
#define TSQUEUE_H

#include "TSDNode.h"
#include <string>

template <class T>
class Queue
{
    private:
        DNode<T>* queue;
        DNode<T>* tail;
        int size;

    public:
        Queue();
        void enqueue(T data);
        T dequeue();
        ~Queue();
};

template <class T>
Queue<T>::Queue()
{
    this->queue = nullptr;
    this->tail = this->queue;
    size = 0;
}


template <class T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(T data)
{
    if (this->tail != NULL)
    {
        this->tail->setNext(new DNode<T>(data));
        this->tail->getNext()->setPrev(this->tail);
        this->tail = this->tail->getNext();
    }
    else
    {
        this->queue = new DNode<T>(data);
        this->tail = this->queue;
    }
    size++;
}

template <class T>
T Queue<T>::dequeue()
{
    T data;

    if (this->queue == nullptr)
    {
        delete this->tail;
        delete this->queue;
        this->tail = nullptr;
        std::string ex = "Exception: Empty Queue\n";
        throw ex;
    }
    else if (this->queue != nullptr)
    {
        data = this->queue->getData();
        DNode<T>* node = this->queue->getNext();
        this->queue->setNext(nullptr);
        this->queue->setPrev(nullptr);
        node->setPrev(nullptr);
        //--------------------------------------------------- crashes here 
        delete this->queue;
        this->queue = node;
    }

    size--;
    return data;
}

template <class T>
Queue<T>::~Queue()
{
    delete this->queue;
    this->queue = nullptr;
    this->tail = nullptr;
}




#endif  /* TSQUEUE_H */
```

Comment: @Golazo This is a **C++** question. Your attempt to edit in the "C" tag is completely inappropriate. If you're not sure, don't attempt to add tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DNode` destructor, you don't want to delete the `next` and `prev` nodes. You only want to delete this node, not everything it links to.

Remove these lines

```
delete this->next;
delete this->prev;
```

Edit: Actually this isn't your problem, because you are clearing out the `next` and `prev` values before you delete the node. I still think it is better to not automatically delete the whole chain, but as long as you are consistent with how you handle node deletion it should still work.

You actually problem is that when you dequeue the last node, you still try to set the `next` pointer of the next node in this line:

```
node->setPrev(nullptr);
//--------------------------------------------------- crashes here
```

At this point `node` is nullptr, so trying to access `node->next` causes a crash. A simple if test is all you need

```
if (node != nullptr)
    node->setPrev(nullptr);
//--------------------------------------------------- no longer crashes here
```

Edit 2:
Also note that in the case where the next node in the queue is `nullptr`, you also want to set the tail to `nullptr`.

Comment: That make sense, I guess the reason I added this was, in my class, coming from linkedlist using nodes. I wanted to make a general node class that would work with anything, including linkedlist, and I always got taught to do it this way so when you delete the head of the linked list, it will chain and delete all nodes within the linked list, so is this my only way of fixing it? thank you btw

Comment: If you automatically delete all the nodes in the linked list when you delete the head node, then there will be no way to remove the head node by itself. Better to just have the node responsible for itself rather than all its siblings. Actually - looking at your code this isn't your problem - I will update my answer.